# How to multiply vector with list items

Tags: python, scripting, particles, vector

I want to draw a point on every vertex of an instanced mesh in a particle system. I put together this short script to do that. It runs without error but nothing happens. The console puts out this message:

```
File "C:\XXXXXX\XXXXXXX\XXXXXXXX\particle draw.blend\Draw Particle Points", line 23, in draw
TypeError: Vector multiplication: not supported between 'Vector' and 'list' types
```

So it's not possible to multiply a vector with a list which makes sense.
What do i have to do to multiply the vector p.location with all inst_verts_coords list items

```
import bpy
import gpu
from mathutils import Matrix
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

# get the depsgraph and the evaluated object   
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
eva_obj = bpy.context.object.evaluated_get(dg)
# assume context object has a ps, use active
ps = eva_obj.particle_systems.active

#obj = bpy.context.active_object
inst_obj = ps.settings.instance_object
inst_obj_verts = inst_obj.data.vertices[0]
inst_verts_coords = [(inst_obj.matrix_world @ inst_obj_verts.co) for inst_obj_verts in inst_obj.data.vertices]

def draw():
    for p in ps.particles:
        #make a matrix for the particles
        M = p.rotation.to_matrix().to_4x4()
        M.translation = p.location

        #translate instance object vertex coords to particle coords
        part_obj_coords = [p.location @ inst_verts_coords]   
        #store vertex coordinates of instance object
        shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
        batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'POINTS', {"pos": part_obj_coords})

        shader.bind()
        shader.uniform_float("color", (1, 1, 0, 1))
        batch.draw(shader)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```

In case I'm missing something else give me a heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inst_verts_coords` is a list of coordinates (Vectors). So you won't be able to apply a matrix to this list. Maybe you want to change the following line (assuming you want to apply matrix to each individual Vector element of the list):

```
part_obj_coords = [p.location @ inst_verts_coords]
```

to:

```
part_obj_coords = [M @ co for co in inst_verts_coords]
```